# Confirming if AngularJS is installed and working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Just following an AngularJS book to read and learn , he has created a test page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title> First App </title>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn btn-default">{{AngularJS}}</div>
<div class = "btn btn-success">Bootsrap</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I go to the URL of the page at: `http://localhost:5000/test.html`

I see a page like this, notice the text is missing from the first button.
Does that mean Angular is not setup correctly?

[image]

Here is also a file to connect to server I think, that's what I have:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic("../angularjs"));
app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct. You can see in the developer tools and Console will show you if there are errors any.
Just add single quotes inside the `{{'AngularJs'}}`.
Look below

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title> First App </title>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn btn-default">{{'AngularJS'}}</div>
<div class = "btn btn-success">Bootsrap</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh I see, It should show the text AngularJS in the first button per book's screen shot.